# Медленное копирование файлов

Tags: ubuntu, файловая-система

Всем привет! Имеется компьютер на Ubuntu 18.04.1 с двумя SATA HDD в Software RAID 1. На диске есть каталог с очень большим количеством мелкий файлов. Схема такая:

1. В каталоге находится 100 каталогов;
2. В каждом таком каталоге находится больше 20 000 каталогов;
3. В каждом каталоге 3 файла: 3, 12 и 40 Kb.

Если я я начинаю копировать новые файлы в этот каталог, то скорость очень низкая - 800 Kb/s. Копирую через mc.

Можно как-то ускорить работу?

Comment: для ясности, какой именно каталог «этот»? какая ФС?

Comment: кстати, а RAID то живой? может один диск уже приказал долго жить?

Comment: ФС: ext4. RAID в норме.

Comment: я бы попробовал ФС с полноценным B-деревом для каталогов — btrfs или XFS... а ещё дефрагментацию (хотя почти наверняка не поможет)... ЗЫ: медленная запись же подразумевается в каталог из пункта (2)?

Comment: В каталог из п.1. Т.к. каталоги из п.2 имеют одинаковые имена в источнике и получателе - то по самим 100 каталогам не хожу.

Comment: А через `rsync -avrhuP --block-size=8192 /from/ /to/` как со скоростью?

Comment: да. собственно проблема может быть в самом `mc` — стоит попробовать копировать через обычный `cp`.